# Using HTML Input's Tag Attribute for SQL Query Without Revealing Database Table Row ID

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a code that loads each row of a mysql table as a "value" attribute of an HTML input element. The idea is that to show the current value and also give the user the ability to update the value.!

[image: Top: the problem statement, Bottom: one possible solution]

The issue is when the user wants to update/change the value, I have to know which row of the table is to be updated. I am using the "id" attribute for this purpose. Currently, I have two solutions, both very similar (please refer to the image above):

1. Use the current value as the "id" attribute, i.e. id="Foo", then use AJAX to form a query that locates the id value through a "SELECT id FROM `user_comment` WHERE `comment`='$currentValue'" and then update the comment
2. The image above: have another table with temporary "alias" for each address. assigned_add[ress] is a random value and will be overwritten once the user is done with page; or the table will be dropped.

The goal is to hide the "real" user_comment.id from the user and not expose it through the "tag" attribute. I am not sure if there is a more common way of doing this, I haven't been able to find anything on SO.

Is there a better way of hiding the id?

Comment: You probably could use a GUID field in user_comment table, then send that GUID instead of ID. Would work the same, but honestly, I dont see the point of hiding id: sending a secondary id as you did, or guid, has to work the same as ID, so, is vulnerable to exact same thing that youre trying to avoid, if there is a vulnerability in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using the actual `id` ?

You might want to secure your code against [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) too

```
SELECT id FROM user_comment WHERE comment='$currentValue'
```

Comment: I *feel* like it wouldn't be secure; I don't have solid reason. My current level of lack of knowledge makes me insecure about it.Yes, I should. Tried to keep the example simple.